# Os navegadores armazenam o arquivo .htaccess em cache?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Escrevi uma expressão regular para fazer com que o site seja sempre redirecionado para o protocolo HTTPS. Porém, não é possível usar HTTPS no localhost. Para conseguir acessar, eu transformei as linhas responsáveis pelo redirecionamento em comentários e, antes de finalmente colocar as edições no ar, desfazer essas alterações no .htaccess para que o redirecionamento seja feito.

Minha dúvida é: o navegador salva o arquivo .htaccess em cache? Pois quando transformei as linhas em comentários e atualizei a página, continuava redirecionando para HTTPS, e quando desabilitei o cache através do DevTools do Chrome, o redirecionamento não foi mais feito.

Comment: já parou pra pensar que o cache é feito no seu navegador ?

Answer (score 3):

Não o navegador nem tem acesso a esse arquivo, ele é uma forma de configurar o Apache no seu servidor, o que acontece é que o navegador faz uma requisição para seu servidor, por exemplo:

```
GET http://dominio.com
```

E armazena a resposta em cache, quando é feita uma segunda requisição igual o navegador nem chega a completar a requisição, em vez disso ele já retorna com aquilo que está em cache, ou seja, as mudanças no arquivo `.htaccess` no servidor nem foram "usadas" (não foi feito uma nova requisição, foi usado o cache), o navegador sequer sabe que houve uma mudança, e usa a versão antiga

Quando você limpa o cache, o navegador apaga aquela resposta do `GET http://...`, então a próxima requisição não é interrompida e realmente chega ao servidor que responde com um novo conteúdo, no seu caso o redirecionamento